# How to detect target of onMouseOver?

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I'm struggling with the problem that some of my

```
$('element').onMouseOver()
and
css-selector:hover
```

aren't working. I'm sure it's  because of some work-around-hacking I need to use to display stuff over other stuff.
Is there any tool which shows me the current target of my `mouseOver-events`?

Comment: Generally, `this` or `$(this)` called from within the event function will work to identify the calling Dom object for things like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event object will tell you the target.

```
document.onmouseover = function (e) { 
    console.log(e.target); 
}
```